# C++ Debugging Help Memory Leak

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks

I am currently working on an assignment and I am struggling greatly with debugging my memory leak. My program runs and passes however, when I upload it for grading my code has a memory leak. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to fix it I would greatly appreciate!

I've tried everything I could think of!

```
#ifndef A2_HPP
#define A2_HPP

#include <algorithm>

class sorted_sc_array {
public:

/*
 * return: none
 * constructor with no argument assign size_ = 0 and ptr_ to null pointer
 */
sorted_sc_array() : size_(0), ptr_(nullptr) {
}

/*
 * return: none
 * destructor delete the pointer ptr_
 */
~sorted_sc_array() {
    delete[] ptr_;
}

/*
 * return: none
 * when assign an object to new object
 */
sorted_sc_array(const sorted_sc_array& A){
    const signed char* str = A.data();
    int sz = A.size_;
    this->size_ = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) this->insert(str[i]);
    delete[] str;
}

/*
 * return: sorted_sc_array
 * overloading of operator =
 */
sorted_sc_array& operator=(const sorted_sc_array& A){
    const signed char* str = A.data();
    int sz = A.size_;
    this->size_ = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) this->insert(str[i]);

}

/*
 * return int
 * return the size of the ptr_
 */
int size() const {
    return size_;
}

/*
 * return char*
 * return the deta stored in the pointer ptr_
 */
const signed char* data() const {
    return ptr_;
}

/*
 * return void
 * add new char to the pointer ptr_ and sort the the new string after the addition
 */
void insert(signed char c) {
    signed char *str = (signed char*)malloc((size_ + 1)*sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) str[i] = ptr_[i];
    str[size_++] = c;
    ptr_ = (signed char*)malloc((size_)*sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; i++) ptr_[i] = str[i];
    std::sort(ptr_, ptr_ + size_);
    delete[] str;
}


private:
int size_; // size of the array
signed char* ptr_; // pointer to the array

}; // class sorted_sc_array

#endif // A2_HPP
```

**This is the testing class:**

```
/*
* File: a2.pp
* Description: testing class a2.hpp
*/

#include <iostream>
#include "a2.hpp"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
sorted_sc_array A;

{
    sorted_sc_array T;
    for (signed char c = -128; c < 127; ++c) T.insert(c);

    T = T;

    sorted_sc_array V = T;
    A = V;
}

const auto first = A.data();
const auto last = first + A.size();

auto size = A.size();
bool res = std::is_sorted(first, last);

if (!res || (A.size() != 255)) std::cout << "fail";
else std::cout << "pass";

std::cout << std::endl;

return 0;
} // main
```

The code compiles and executes, with a "pass" however there is a memory leak somewhere ! :(

Comment: Use valgrind, the program which detects memory leaks in other programs.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what the error you get. I don't immediately see a memory leak, but I see an obvious double-free. Actually, I do see a memory leak...

Comment: I am not receiving any errors. My code compiles and runs, however when I upload it to grade, the grader shows a memory leak.

Comment: You should use free() to free memory assigned using malloc, not delete[].

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

In the copy constructor:

```
delete[] str;
```

This deletes the other object's buffer. The other object's destructor will attempt to `delete[]` its own buffer again, when it gets destroyed. This will result in memory corruption, and undefined behavior.

The obvious memory leak is in your `insert()`:

```
ptr_ = (signed char*)malloc((size_)*sizeof(char));
```

There are two simultaneous bugs here.

1. Using `malloc` for a buffer that the destructor will eventually `delete[]`. Only `new`-ed objects can be `delete[]`d. Using `delete` for a `malloc`-ed content is undefined behavior.
2. The previous contents of `ptr_` are not explicitly `delete`d, thus leaking memory.

The `insert()`, overall, is doing unnecessary allocation. There's no need to allocate a buffer twice, there. Only one allocation is sufficient: allocate, copy over the content to the new buffer, `delete` the old `ptr_`, and set `ptr_` to the newly-allocated buffer.